# python-socketio asyncio client: Is it possible to know when emit is completelly send data over the wire to server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-socketio

Do python-socketio or underlying python-engineio have any kind of confirmation that specific message was completely delivered to other side, similar to what TCP does to ensure all data was successfully transferred to other side?

I have kind of pubsub service built on python-socketio server, which sends back ok/error status when request has been processed. But in my python-socketio client sometimes I just need fire and forget some message to pubsub but I have to wait it was completely delivired before I terminate my application.

So, my naive code:

```
await sio.emit("publish", {my message})
```

it seems the await above is just scheduling send over wire to asyncio, but does not wait for send to complete. I suppose it's by design. Just need to know is it possible to know when send is complete or not.

Comment: The only way to get a reliable ACK is when the *process* on the other side sends it, i.e. it must be a part of the communication protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO has ACK packets that can be used for the receiving side to acknowledge receipt of an event.

When using the Python client and server, you can replace the `emit()` with `call()` to wait for the ack to be received. The return value of `call()` is whatever data the other side returned in the acknowledgement.

But not that for this to work the other side also needs to be expanded to send this ACK packets. If your other side is also Python, an event handler can issue an ACK simply by returning something from the handler function. The data that you return is included in the ACK packet. If the other side is JavaScript, you get a callback function passed as a last argument into your handler. The handler needs to call this function passing any data that it wants to send to the other side as response.

Comment: Bot sides are python-socketio.

Comment: I just wonder will such ACK be any different from my current situation when server emits back some answer to me?

Comment: The ACK packet is very much like the EVENT packet, with the exception that it contains a reference to the originating event. If the other side replies with a standalone event, then there is nothing that links the event with its response, so it would be up to your application to interpret the responding event as a response, for example based on data included in the payload.

Comment: In case you are interested, here is the reference docs for the EVENT and ACK packets in Socket.IO: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol#2---event

Comment: Thanks a lot, you shed some bright light on the underlying protocol. Previously I had no idea what is the proper idiomatic way for building typical request-answer protocol with socketio. Now that all becomes more clear.